# Are MuPAD functions deprecated, or just the notebooks?

Tags: matlab, mupad

I see the message:

> MuPAD® notebooks will be removed in a future release. Use MATLAB®
>   live scripts instead.
>
> To convert a MuPAD notebook file to a MATLAB live script file, see
>   convertMuPADNotebook. MATLAB live scripts support most MuPAD
>   functionality, although there are some differences. For more
>   information, see Convert MuPAD Notebooks to MATLAB Live Scripts.

I'm not interested in the notebook feature, but I do on occasion find some rather handy MuPAD functions, e.g. those in `combinat` - are these deprecated, or just the notebooks (neither of which am I very familiar with).

Comment: The more docs I read, I'm inclined to think these functions are deprecated for MATLAB.